# Adding data from a partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Always on the same project (for those who aswered me), I have a entity "Person" which is in relation with an entity VehicleFuelCard (relation one to many). In my "Create Person" view, I included by AJAX code a partial view which is in fact a "Create Fuel Card" view :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function AddVehicleFuelCard() {
    $("#test").load("@Url.Action("AddVehicleFuelCard","Person", 
        new { personViewModel = Model })");
}
</script>
```

And call it in the PersonController :

```
public ActionResult AddVehicleFuelCard(PersonViewModel personViewModel)
{
    ViewBag.Id_VehicleFuelCardCompany = new SelectList(db.VehicleFuelCardCompanies, "Id_VehicleFuelCardCompany", "Name");

    return PartialView("PartialVehicleFuelCard", personViewModel);
}
```

Here is the ViewModel that I use :

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private Person _person;
    public List<VehicleFuelCard> listVehicleFuelCard;
    public Person Person
    {
        get
        {
            return this._person;
        }    
    }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        this._person = new Person();
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        this._person = person;
    }

    public VehicleFuelCard NewVehicleFuelCard
    {
        get
        {
            VehicleFuelCard element = new VehicleFuelCard();
            element.Person = this.Person;
            Person.VehicleFuelCards.Add(element);

            return element;
        }
    }

    public PhoneCard NewPhoneCard
    {
        get
        {
            PhoneCard element = new PhoneCard();
            Person.PhoneCards.Add(element);

            return element;
        }
    }

    public ProductAllocation NewProductAllocation
    {
        get
        {
            ProductAllocation element = new ProductAllocation();
            Person.ProductAllocations.Add(element);

            return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Create Actions in my controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name");
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Person/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonViewModel personViewModel)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Persons.AddObject(personViewModel.Person);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name", personViewModel.Person.Id_ProductPackageCategory);

    return View(personViewModel);
}
```

Any idea to add a Fuel Card while I'm adding a Person? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post post both `Person` and `Fuel Card` on the same request you will need to update your the data on the client side to include `Fuel Card` as part of your request.

That's on the client side, on the server side you could add `Fuel Card` as a nested object to `Person` (watch out for cyclic references when serializing to the client though).

Here is rough example. Update your object on the client side to include both `PersonViewModel` and `Fuel Card`. For example, create an object with javascript:

```
var person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:50,eyecolor:"blue"};
```

Add your nested object

```
person.FuelCard = {property1 ="val1", property2="Val2};
```

Then post it to the server using Ajax.

```
$.post('/Person/Create', person, function(data) {
   // do something on success
 });
```

Comment: Thanks... I think I have to make some research because I didn't catch everything you've explained. But thanks.

Comment: np, I've expanded my answer.